# Cannot CURL to Docker container from another running Docker instance (using Kafka connector)

Tags: postgresql, docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to connect 2 microservices using Kafka Connector in Spring using Docker containers.

Refer to this [Gitlab link](https://gitlab.com/aymanapatel/donorservice/-/tree/complete-demo) for project details.

I have 2 containers in Spring.

1. **s1-pledgeservice**
2. **s1-donorservice**

First, I need to run **s1-pledgeservice** (through `startup.sh` in the corresponding project folder) and it works fine.

But for second step, when I run **s1-donorservice** (through `startup.sh` in the corresponding project folder), I get an exception in **s1-pledgeservice** and **s1-donorservice**

**s1-pledgeservice** exception:

```
kafka-connect    | 2020-12-23 05:53:31,677 ERROR  ||  Uncaught exception in REST call to /connectors/   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.ConnectExceptionMapper]
kafka-connect    | java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**s1-donorservice** exception:

```
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
", ning: Couldn't read data from file "sql/postgres-connect-config.json
```

Looking at docker images, and it seems to be running fine.

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                                                                        NAMES
c149865fd1ac   debezium/connect:1.2            "/docker-entrypoint.…"   59 minutes ago   Up 12 minutes   8778/tcp, 9092/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8083->8083/tcp, 9779/tcp                                         kafka-connect
58b557f8d277   oawofolu/ssm-pledgeservice:v1   "java -jar /app.jar"     59 minutes ago   Up 12 minutes   0.0.0.0:8101->8080/tcp                                                                       pledge-consumer
1da693b393f8   debezium/kafka:1.2              "/docker-entrypoint.…"   59 minutes ago   Up 12 minutes   8778/tcp, 9779/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp                                                   kafka
30df710d8120   debezium/postgres:12            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   59 minutes ago   Up 12 minutes   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp                                                                       postgres
aa4b9d124f5b   debezium/zookeeper:1.2          "/docker-entrypoint.…"   59 minutes ago   Up 12 minutes   0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2888->2888/tcp, 8778/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3888->3888/tcp, 9779/tcp   zookeeper
```

Note that I am running Docker from a Debian distribution in WSL2.

Comment: I think you must check and edit sql/postgres-connect-config.json. Database hostname must be localhost, not postgres?

Comment: Changed database hostname to localhost. Same error

Comment: The URL syntax is protocol-dependent.Try add protocol to call curl URL `curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8083/connectors/ --data-binary "@sql/postgres-connect-config.json"`